What is the in-universe justification for material hierarchical perks (such as quarters) in Starfleet?
The answer to this question indicates that there are hierarchical differences in crew quarters on, for example, the Enterprise. Apparently, Lower Decks is considered canon, and so I seem to understand that the enlisted are not merely given less spacious quarters or forced to share rooms, but that they actually sleep in beds built into the walls of the main corridors.
Whilst it is of course unobjectionable that a starship would need a hierarchical command structure, it strikes me as odd that the radically egalitarian post-scarcity society of the Federation would decide to implement hierarchical perks in the matter of living space. That is, unless there were very serious practical requirements.
For that reason, I could understand if the Enterprise were a warship, and it was critically important for combat reasons that the hull size be kept to a minimum. Or if there were critical material shortages. These sorts of factors would make it reasonable that a captain or a commander or a lieutenant would get a larger room than the enlisted; it is better to have a larger room, as it improves comfort, allows for better mental recuperation, &c, and those benefits would be best allocated to the command staff first, for the greatest gain to overall efficiency, if there were a shortage.
But the Enterprise is not a warship, and the Federation does not seem to be in any danger of running out of manufacturing capability, nor much concerned with keeping their ships to a tight profile. The Enterprise is basically a spaceborne city, complete with such amenities as gardens and schools, and the accepted answer to this question indicates that the Enterprise is probably up to 90% vacant on an average day. And the design of the ship in-totum, as well as the saucer segment specifically, doesn't seem especially concerned with the prospect of presenting a less easy-to-target profile.
So, why the unnecessary hierarchy? It seems tantamount to saying "the higher ranked are better than the lower, and they deserve better things (even when everyone could be equal)", which doesn't seem very much like the Federation to me.
Is there an in-universe reason for it? Does Starfleet think it "builds character" to be made to suffer simply for being lower in rank? Is it just that the writers found that mimicking the real navy/military was an easy way to go, and didn't think of the in-universe implications?

It might be that canon is to be taken with a pinch of salt given the comedy nature of the Lower Decks show. Maybe consider it a form of autobiographical content, true in broad strokes, but with tongue in cheek self depreciation about the difficulties and influence of the enlisted on the plot.

Well, the other thing to be taken with a pinch of salt is the Federation's egalitarian and post-scarcity nature in the first place. We already know that this wasn't the case in the colony that Tasha Yar grew up in, and there's a surprising amount of working-class resentment in Miles O'Brien's attitude to officers.

It could also be true that, in a post-scarcity society, Starfleet has found it necessary to create artificial scarcities (space, luxuries) in order to give personnel sufficient motivation to aspire to higher ranks.

While I don't know of anywhere it's explicitly spelled-out in canon, my head canon is that it's a way to induce crewmembers to seek advancement.

The junior officers are sleeping in the hallway bunks in Lower Decks.

@Shawn so where do the enlisted sleep? Outside?! :)

@Jontia Good question. Maybe there's a huge fo'c'sle with places to hang hammocks.

@Jontia In the Jefferies tubes. Rutherford keeps waking them up.

I wonder how much simple tradition plays into it? Officers traditionally have better quarters and other benefits over non-commissioned officers, so just keep that going?

@DavidW That would certainly fly in the face of the suggested Federation society, and the explicit claims made in The Neutral Zone that members of the Federation act only from their own drive to grow, contribute, succeed, etc. Not to mention that if creature comforts motivated them, they would probably just be motivated to leave StarFleet and have comfy lives on Earth. (Tasha Yar & company excluded)

Any reasonable person should not count LD---or any new Trek, for that matter---as canon.

@HamSandwich Canon is just the stuff people that are paid to write for a franchise have to make an effort to be consistent with, nothing more and nothing less

@DanielRoseman Turkana IV isn't a great example; it was an Earth colony whose government collapsed in a coup and which subsequently left the Federation entirely
